# Why drop_duplicates function in pandas dose not work with object type?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

#### I use drop duplicates in pandas python but it doesn't work with me !

I use in-place=true but i have object d-type and date how can i solve it and i need all columns being checked 
For example

```
  A      |       B      |    C
```

0  |112     |    11/12/2003    |    As

1  |113     |    11/12/2003     |    As

2  |112     |    11/12/2003     |    As

0 and 2 are duplicated , but in my case dose not show  as duplicated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `drop_duplicates` on 1 column and then use the indices on that to get the result:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[112, '11/12/2003', 'As'],
[113, '11/12/2003', 'As'],
[112, '11/12/2003', 'As']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df[df.index.isin(df['A'].drop_duplicates().index)]
```

Output:

```
     A           B   C
0  112  11/12/2003  As
1  113  11/12/2003  As
```

Comment: thank you , but  in my case this dose not work because  I want all the columns being checked not only the date

Comment: then simply call `df.drop_duplicates()` should be enough, no?